# What is the iText 7 equivalent of FontSelector.Process?

Tags: fonts, itext, itext7

I'm beginning the process of updating code written against iText5 to work with iText7.

Is there a similar mechanism in iText7 to the FontSelector class, where you would load up fonts and the "Process" action would automatically determine which font to use (and return a formatted pdf "chunk" that could be added to the document)? Here's the code snippet (this is C++, but my "native" language is C#, so feel free to answer with C#).

```
try {
    doc = gcnew Document();
    pdfWriter = PdfWriter::GetInstance(doc, pdfStream);

    FontSelector^ selector = gcnew FontSelector();
    selector->AddFont(gcnew Font(BaseFont::CreateFont("Fonts\\cour.ttf"), BaseFont::IDENTITY_H, BaseFont::NOT_EMBEDDED), 10.0f));
    selector->AddFont(gcnew Font(BaseFont::CreateFont("Fonts\\arialuni.ttf"), BaseFont::IDENTITY_H, BaseFont::NOT_EMBEDDED), 10.0f));

    doc->Open();
    while (textReader->EndOfStream == false)
    {
        String^ line = textReader->ReadLine();
        doc->Add(selector->Process(line + "\n"));
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A similar mechanism is indeed available in iText7. And there is even a way to make it work implicitly without processing chunks and adding them manually to the document. The class you are looking for is called `FontProvider`. To start with, you need to create an instance and add your fonts to it:

```
FontProvider provider = new FontProvider();
provider.AddFont(fontsFolder + "NotoSans-Regular.ttf");
provider.AddFont(fontsFolder + "FreeSans.ttf");
provider.GetFontSet().AddFont(fontsFolder + "Puritan2.otf", PdfEncodings.IDENTITY_H);
```

Then, you need `layout`'s `Document` instance which might have been created like this, or in any other way:

```
PdfDocument pdfDoc = new PdfDocument(new PdfWriter(outFileName));
Document doc = new Document(pdfDoc);
```

Then, all you need is set the font provider to the document and, most importantly, **set the preferred font name to trigger the font selector mechanism**. If you don't select the preferred font name and don't set `PdfFont` explicitly, the default font, `Helvetica`, will be used.

The code to do the above might look like following:

```
doc.SetFontProvider(provider);
doc.SetFont("NotoSans");
Paragraph paragraph = new Paragraph("Hello world! \u05E2\u05B4\u05D1\u05B0\u05E8\u05B4\u05D9\u05EA\u202C");
doc.Add(paragraph);
```

Finally, don't forget to close the document:

```
doc.Close();
```